# Powershell error while trying to create Scheduled Task? Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Argument'

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a scheduled task that runs when the system starts up. I am creating this scheduled task in PowerShell with the following code.

```
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
    
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
    
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $sendEmailCommand -Argument $args
    
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Send Restart Notification" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force`
```

The following are the variables:

```
$sendEmailCommand = "C:\Test\Test.exe"
$args = "-m smtp.gmail.com -p 587 -u myemail -p mypassword -t my message -o tls=yes -k MyEmailSubject -g recipientEmailAddr"
```

However, when I run the above script, I receive the following error.

```
New-ScheduledTaskAction : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Argument'. Cannot convert value to type
```

If I remove the `-Argument` from the line with `New-ScheduledTaskAction`, then it runs just fine with no errors and the task appears in Task Scheduler as expected. This is what that line of code looks like:

```
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $sendEmailCommand
```

I have tried various permutations of quotes and no quotes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$args` is powershell reserved keyword. Use other name for the variable.

More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#args)